# CA1008: Enums should have zero value convert to CQL(Code Query Language)

Tags: ndepend, cql

I'm trying to CQL transforms all Code Analysis for Managed Code Warnings from msdn for use in NDepend. The CA1008 which says that enumerations should have a value equal to zero, is giving me problems. Can you help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done yet with CQL since it doesn't know about enumeration values numbers.

However, in the *CQL Query Explorer panel* you'll find a group named *.NET Framework Usage* that proposes 30 default rules relative to what FxCop is doing.

[image]